# zlib's compress function is not doing anything. Why?

Tags: c++, c, compression, zlib

```
before = new unsigned char[mSizeNeeded*4];

uLong value = compressBound(mSizeNeeded*4);
after = new unsigned char[value];

compress(after, &value, before, mSizeNeeded*4);

fwrite(&after, 1, value, file);
```

'before' has a bunch of audio data stored into it and I am trying to compress it and store it into 'after'. I then write it into a file. The file is the same size as the original file, it also contains the same data that was in before (as far as I can tell).

Compress also returns OK so I know that the compression is not failing.

---

Okay, so it looks like my only problem is somewhere in the compression (I think). I am able to run compress and then I can uncompress and get the correct data out. Also, it is writing into the file and fwrite returns 561152 but the count (value) is 684964. So it looks like something is wrong with fwrite. I looked more carefully and the after data is different than the before data.

561152 is the same size as the original audio data in a .wav file that I have (stripped of the .wav headers of course).

---

Answer (score 0):

Based on your *original* text:

```
fwrite (&before, ...
```

> I am trying to compress it and store it into 'after'. I then *write it into a file.*

I think not. You are writing the *original* data to the file, you should probably be writing `after` instead.

---

The other thing you should get in the habit of doing is checking return values from functions that you care about. In other words, `compress()` will tell you if a problem occurs yet you seem to be totally ignoring the possibility.

Similarly, `fwrite()` also uses its return value to indicate whether it was successful or not. Since you haven't included the code showing how that's set up, this is also a distinct possibility. In particular `fwrite` is under *no* obligation to write your entire block to the file in one hit (device may be full, etc), that's why it *has* a return value, so you can detect and adjust for that situation. Often, a better option than:

```
fwrite (&after, 1, value, file);
```

is:

```
fwrite (&after, value, 1, file);
```

since the latter will always give you one for a fully successful write, something else for a failure of some description.

That would be my first step in establishing where the problem lies.

On top of that, there are numerous other (generally-applicable) methods you can use to track down the issue, such as:

- outputting all variables after they change or are set (like the return values of functions, `after`, `before`, `value` and so on).
- delete the output file before running your program, to ensure it's created afresh.
- run the code through a debugger so you can *see* what's happening under the covers.
- clearing `after` to all zero bytes (or a known pattern) to ensure you don't get stale data in there.

---

And, as a final approach (given that the zlib source code is freely available), you can also modify (or debug into) *it* so that you can clearly see what's going on under the covers.

Comment: Sorry thats how i figured out that it was the same data. I just forgot to change it back. The file should still be smaller since value will be the size of 'after' after the compression

Comment: Yes it returned a success value

Comment: The first form of `fwrite()` is preferable, because it tells you how many bytes were written. The second form cannot tell you about a partial write.

Comment: @EJP, that depends *entirely* on how you're using it, which is why I used the word "often", rather than a blanket assertion like "is preferable" :-) If you don't care about the file content unless it's fully written (such as if you're going to fail and ignore the file), my method is preferable. If you're going to go back and try to write the rest of the data and hopefully succeed eventually, your assertion is correct. As with most things, there are pros and cons to all methods.